# Cannot get data from table with watir-webdriver

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to Ruby and watir-webdriver and I am trying to pull data from a website and cannot figure out how to access a particular cell in an HTML table. I cannot find any id, name, or class to distinguish the cell I need. I am thinking that the table is generated dynamically. Here is what I have so far:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new:firefox
browser.goto 'http://oh-scioto-auditor.publicaccessnow.com/search.aspx'

browser.text_field(:id => "fldSearchFor").set '011234000'

browser.button(:name => 'btnSearch').click

browser.link(:text => 'Parcel Detail').click

puts browser.table(:id => 'lxT380').exists?

browser.td(:index => 0).each do |data|
    puts data.text
end
```

When I use firebug in firefox to get the unique selector this is what I get:

```
#lxT380 > div:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1)
```

It may be useful but like I said I'm new to Ruby and I am not sure what to do with it. Any input would be apprecitated.

Comment: How as a user would you decide which cell is the one you want?

Comment: @Justin Ko, sorry should have mentioned that I am trying to get the billing address that is listed just below the cell that contains "Tax Payer Address:"

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the problem with the table is that there are distinguishing attributes. As a result, I think your best choice is to locate cells by:

1. Finding known text and
2. Then finding the desired cell in relation to that.

For example, the tax payer address is inside this table (which is nested within a bunch of other non-descriptive tables):

```
<table class=" ui-corner-all" border="1" width="250">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="ui-state-default">Property Address:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" height="95" valign="top">3069  GEPHART RD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="ui-state-default">Tax Payer Address:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" height="95" valign="top">FAULKNER PATRICK EUGENE +<br>2112  GEPHART RD<br>WHEELERSBURG OH 45694<br>USA </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To get the payer address, find the row containing the "Tax Payer Address:" heading:

```
tax_payer_address_label = browser.tr(:text => 'Tax Payer Address:')
```

Get the following row, which is assumed to be the address:

```
tax_payer_address = tax_payer_address_label.tr(:xpath => './following-sibling::tr')
```

Finally, get the text of the row/cell:

```
puts tax_payer_address.text
#=> FAULKNER PATRICK EUGENE +
#=> 2112 GEPHART RD
#=> WHEELERSBURG OH 45694
#=> USA
```

As a complete working script:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new:firefox
browser.goto 'http://oh-scioto-auditor.publicaccessnow.com/search.aspx'

browser.text_field(:id => "fldSearchFor").set '011234000'
browser.button(:name => 'btnSearch').click
browser.link(:text => 'Parcel Detail').click

tax_payer_address_label = browser.tr(:text => 'Tax Payer Address:')
tax_payer_address = tax_payer_address_label.tr(:xpath => './following-sibling::tr')
puts tax_payer_address.text
#=> FAULKNER PATRICK EUGENE +
#=> 2112 GEPHART RD
#=> WHEELERSBURG OH 45694
#=> USA
```

Note that you could also use a single xpath, but it is not as nice to read/write:

```
puts browser.tr(:xpath => '//tr[normalize-space(.) = "Tax Payer Address:"]/following-sibling::tr').text
#=> FAULKNER PATRICK EUGENE +
#=> 2112 GEPHART RD
#=> WHEELERSBURG OH 45694
#=> USA
```

Comment: If I need watir help, I just search as *watir* and your name.. All help comes into the search list. Great Justin. +1